# Entering South Africa on EXPIRED SA passport (as a dual passport holder(AUS/SA))

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, dual-nationality, south-african-citizens

My husband is travelling back to SA in 3 weeks. 
He is a dual citizen AUS/SA. His SA passport is expired.
What should he do when crossing immigration controls in South Africa?

1. Enter on AUS passport and hope they dont notice his place of birth 'Cape Town'

or

2. Enter on expired SA passport and just tell them he made a mistake by not checking it early enough to renew for this trip?

Comment: Not an answer, but a lot of us ex-South Africans actually were unaware of the law to return on SA passports until recently, and I know many who have gone back with say, a NZ or Aus or UK passport and nobody batted an eyelid.  All entered on their foreign passport as a tourist.  I *suspect* the law is not policed, but like I said, this is just from word of mouth from several dual passport holders that I know.

Comment: Strictly speaking, he should do neither; he should apply at the South African consulate for a new passport or emergency travel document.

Comment: If the situation is anything like that in the US, it isn't at all strict, and there will be no problem to travel on the Australian passport, as noted by @MarkMayo.  I looked at the High Commission's website, and passports seem to take a long time, while emergency documents are said to be limited to "strictly" emergency situations.  Still, you might want to call them.  Mark, were any of the people you write of born in SA?

Comment: @phoog all of them.

Comment: @MarkMayo can you reconcile their experience with the story in [Richard's comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50412/dual-citizen-return-to-home-country-south-africa-on-expired-passport#comment100059_50412) where "they only got more mad"?

Comment: @phoog well that person overstayed, so then complicating things probably didn't help her case :/  In all cases I know of, they had zero issues, but they entered on their foreign passport.